# Reproduce AES decryption method from C# in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, encryption, aes

I am trying to reproduce the following C# decryption method in JavaScript.

This method is used to decrypt short strings: names, addresses, email addresses, etc.

It feels tantalisingly close, because the strings I have been able to "successfully" decrypt seem partially decrypted.

For instance, some of the emails look like this: `x"R�Îd¹1gtWÈ2)web@example.com`

## CSharp

```cs
public static readonly byte[] INIT_VECTOR = { 0x00, 0x00, ... };

public static string Decrypt(string cipherText) {

  string EncryptionKey = "Some Encryption Key";

  byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

  using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
  {
​
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, INIT_VECTOR);

    encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
    encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
      using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
      {
        cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
        cs.Close();
      }
      cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
  }

  return cipherText;
}
```

## JavaScript

```
import atob from 'atob';
import forge from 'node-forge';

const InitVector = [0x00, ...];
const EncryptionKey = 'Some Encryption Key';

const iv = Buffer.from(InitVector).toString();

const convertBase64StringToUint8Array = input => {
  const data = atob(input);
  const array = Uint8Array.from(data, b => b.charCodeAt(0));

  return array;
};

const decrypt = cipher => {
  const cipherArray = convertBase64StringToUint8Array(cipher);

  const key = forge.pkcs5.pbkdf2(EncryptionKey, iv, 1000, 32);

  const decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher('AES-CBC', key);

  decipher.start({ iv });

  decipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(cipherArray, 'raw'));

  const result = decipher.finish();

  if (result) {
    return decipher.output.data;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: In C# the default mode is  CBC. You should transfer the IV. In C# the IV is random. In the JS it is all 0. The partial decryption says that the IV is incorrect since it is effecting only one block, the first block. **Note:** CBC is archaic stick to Authenticated encryption mode as AES-GCM if there are no restrictions. **Note 2:** usually the IV is prepended to the ciphertext.

Comment: You need to use the same salt in JS as you used in C#. Thus you need to send the salt along with the enciphered data. That's ok, that salt does not need to be secret, it just needs to be unpredictable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [kelalaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1820553/kelalaka) I managed to figure this out!

This was the code I ended up with.

```
import atob from 'atob';
import forge from 'node-forge';

const InitVector = [0x00, ...];
const EncryptionKey = 'Some Encryption Key';

const initKey = Buffer.from(InitVector).toString(); // Changed this to `initKey`

const convertBase64StringToUint8Array = input => {
  const data = atob(input);
  const array = Uint8Array.from(data, b => b.charCodeAt(0));

  return array;
};

const decrypt = cipher => {
  const cipherArray = convertBase64StringToUint8Array(cipher);

  const key = forge.pkcs5.pbkdf2(EncryptionKey, iv, 1000, 32);

  /**
   * Added the following
   * Note the key size = 48
   *  This was due to the fact that the C# dictated that
   *  the IV was 16 bytes, starting at the end of the key.
   */
  const keyAndIV = forge.pkcs5.pbkdf2(encryptionKey, initKey, 1000, 32 + 16);

  /**
   * Therefore, we cut the iv from the new string
   */
  const iv = keyAndIV.slice(32, 32 + 16); // 16 bytes

  const decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher(
    'AES-CBC',
    forge.util.createBuffer(key)
  );

  decipher.start({ iv });

  decipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(cipherArray, 'raw'));

  const result = decipher.finish();

  if (result) {
    return decipher.output.data;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```