# Node.js Aes crypt -> C# aes decrypt

Tags: c#, node.js, encryption, aes

I'm making an api which creates an encrypted string and will be consumed by many C# app. My problem is the encrypted string/bytes on c# doesn't give the same output than node.js

This is my node code.

```
const  key = "01234567890123456789012345678901";
const  iv = "0123456789012345";

function cryptTokn(text){
    var keyBytes = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(Key);
    var ivBytes = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(iv);
    var textBytes = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(text);
    
    var aesOfb= new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ofb(keyBytes, ivBytes);
    var encryptedBytes = aesOfb.encrypt(textBytes);

    // To print or store the binary data, you may convert it to hex
    var encryptedHex = aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptedBytes);
    console.log(encryptedHex);
    return encryptedHex;
}
```

My C# Code

```
private static byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("01234567890123456789012345678901");        
private static byte[] iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0123456789012345");
private static int keySize = 256;
private static int ivSize = 128;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Text to crypt...");
    string plain = Console.ReadLine();
    using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
    {
        aes.KeySize = keySize;
        aes.BlockSize = ivSize;
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.IV = iv;

        byte[] encrypted = Encrypt(plano, aes.Key, aes.IV);
        var enc = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted);
        Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted data: {enc}");
    }
}
    
static byte[] Encrypt(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    byte[] encrypted;
    using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
    {
        // Create encryptor    
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {  
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                    sw.Write(plainText);
                encrypted = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    // Return encrypted data    
    return encrypted;
}
```

I don't mind changing the whole code, but I need to cipher data on node.js then read it and decypher in .net framework and .net core apps.

Edit. using this node.js lib
https://www.npmjs.com/package/aes-js

Comment: Without getting too deep into your code, what exactly are you comparing? The `byte[]` output from c# compared to the "hex" output of the node.js code?

Comment: I did the opposite a few years ago – decrypting strings in JS that were encrypted by C#, and documented how in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57928974/reproduce-aes-decryption-method-from-c-sharp-in-javascript). It may be useful for comparison. I also used [`node-forge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge), so YMMV.

Comment: I've compared from string to bytes, in this point i'm comparing on debug time the bytes.
@Labu i'll check that code, thank you